# hinge loss vs. square of hinge loss components

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

We can define the hinge loss to be

$$
L(y,t) = \max\{0,1-yt\}
$$

We can also have a variation such that the loss now becomes:
$$
L(y,t) = \max\{0,(1-yt)^2 \}
$$

When would you want to use one over the other?

Comment: The second is unnecessarily complicated as it simply says $(1-yt)^2$. As to the question, well that depends on what you think of negative values, and relative sizes. If you think negative non-zero values are as bad positive non-zero values, it is obviously not suitable with the first one. Similarly, if you think a residual of 2 instead of 1 is more than twice as bad, you need something else than linear, such as quadratic. In other words, it depends on what you are doing